# How to detect Network driver removed programmatically In delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

I was looking for some Windows API that will give me notification for any change in the Local Area Connection Properties.I tried Searching for the Entry in the Registry which it modifies after we check or uncheck the driver name but could find it.

I have also attached an image if any one has any confusion in understanding my question.

[image: The network settings tab]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the Windows API for [Network Awareness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It would be great if Delphi example implementations were readily available but they are not. The API's are all COM interfaces and you will have to find out how to use these within Delphi yourself. That is another question. However, for the INetworkConnection, [this](http://idxdmitry.blogspot.nl/2013/05/delphi-enumerator-for-ienumvariant.html) may get you started.

Comment: Don't know why this question is downvoted, although it has been edited, so it may be that it is not related to the topic itself. The lack of Delphi examples on the web of how to use these interfaces makes it a valid question I believe.